# How can I link linux shell files?

Tags: bash, shell

```
  #!/bin/bash
  echo "Please, select your choice (1-4):"
  echo 1- Add Course
  echo 2- Delete Course
  echo 3- Search Course
  echo 4- exit
  read input

  case $input in
    1)
            script1
            ;;
    2)
            script2
            ;;
    3)
            script3
            ;;
    4)
            exit 0
            ;;
    *)
            echo Invalid choice
  esac
```

> 1 is associated with the file Add.sh
>
> 2 is associated with the file delete.sh
>
> 3 is associated with the file seatch.sh
>
> 4 is to exit

Comment: What should happen when someone presses `1`?

Comment: The commands in "add.sh" must be executed.  But the code is not working

Comment: Replace`script1` with `/path/to/your/add.sh` and make sure it is executable (`chmod u+x /path/to/your/add.sh`).

Comment: Probably a copy/paste error, but missing the double semi-colon after "Invalid choice".

Answer (score 0):

Using the builtin
[`select`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-select)
command means you don't need to reinvent menus.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# assuming all the scripts reside in the same directory as this one
script_path="$(dirname "$0")"

PS3="Please, select your choice: "
select choice in "Add Course" "Delete Course" "Search Course" "exit"; do
    case $input in
        "Add Course")    bash "$script_path/add.sh" ;;
        "Delete Course") bash "$script_path/delete.sh" ;;
        "Search Course") bash "$script_path/search.sh" ;;
        exit)            break ;;
    esac
done
```

I could get fancier to avoid the duplicated strings, but that's unneeded complexity.

Depending on the contents of those scripts, you might want to `source` them instead of running them in a different process. It might be simple to even put them in functions in the current script instead of having to maintain several separate files.